# WooCommerce payment status or token - how to get_

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment, hook-woocommerce

I am newbie at PHP.

I am trying to check if the user has a payment token or some other value that confirms they have made a payment.

I want to redirect the page if the payment status is empty 9they have not made payment yet).

I tried :

```
<?php  

 if(get_post_type()=="sfwd-lessons"){
     $lesson_id=get_the_ID();
 }else{
     $lesson_id=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'lesson_id',true);
 }

  $value = get_field( "new_field", $lesson_id );
   $user_status=get_wpmg_woocommerce_payment_tokens($user_id,'token_id',true);
   //$user_status='';
if(!empty($value) && empty($user_status)){
    header('Location: https://xx/checkouts/checkout-page/');
    exit;
    ?>
```

but I dot think "get_wpmg_woocommerce_payment_tokens" is a valid call

is there another get_ call I can make to check if payment token_id is empty for that user?

or is there a way on the woo commerce thank you page to write new field "payment_status" complete to user_meta_data

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This hook `woocommerce_thankyou` will fire each time you refresh the thankyou page.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'after_order_placed', 10, 1);

function after_order_placed($order_id) {

    if (!$order_id)
        return;
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    if ($order->get_date_paid()) {
        // Order is paid - Do something
    } else {
        // Order is NOT paid - Do something else
    }
}
```

The best hook for sending some data to a third party when order payment is completed is `woocommerce_payment_complete` .

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'after_payment_complete');

function payment_complete_callback($order_id) {
    if (!$order_id)
        return;
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    if ($order->get_date_paid()) {
        // Order is paid - Do something
    } else {
        // Order is NOT paid - Do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @aidan545 it's already resolved you can check from the below link in the link it will give you a proper way for accessing all the order details with woocommerce object WC_Order

Link: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details)